# Error in executing SQL statement with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create a new database `'sakila'` with `pgAdmin III` in my local `PostgreSQL` database, then executed these sql statements:

[sakila-schema.sql](https://github.com/restsql/restsql-sdk/blob/master/WebContent/database/postgresql/sakila-schema.sql) then [sakila-data.sql](https://raw.github.com/restsql/restsql-sdk/master/WebContent/database/postgresql/sakila-data.sql)

The first statement executed without error, however the second SQL did produced error when executed:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 112: 1 PENELOPE GUINESS 2006-02-15 09:34:33
          ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 2511
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: It seems pgAdmin does not support `copy from stdin..`. Try to run the script using `psql`

Comment: I have succeeded in creating and populating the data here. I first had to do (from psql -U postgres postgres) `create database sakila`, and then (from the commandline) `psql -U postgres sakila <sakila-schema.sql`, followed by `psql -U postgres sakila <sakila-data.sql`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't `COPY FROM stdin` with pgAdmin, you have to use [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html) tool, the problem is that  pgAdmin is not a console application, there is no easily usable stdin so you can't COPY from Standard Input .

Comment: I tried running "/i C:/postgresql/sakila-data.sql" (without the quotes), no errors but it didn't do a thing, since if I SELECT from the database tables its empty...

Comment: @xybrek \i not /i , and I'd say you didn't get any error because, except for backslash commands, psql doesn't respond to a command until a semicolon is found in the input.

Comment: @xybrek try to import with psql -U postgres db_name < file.sql